# How to reduce data by commands of awk?

Tags: awk

For example, there is a data file named tmp.dat, in that, the data is this form:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7

.  .  .  .  .  . .
```

My target is to extract only x3 and x4 these two columns.

How can I use command of awk to do that reduction work?

I know the method using C/C++ with open commands, but it is troublesome.

Comment: I downvoted this question, because you can very easily find the answer online.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 awk '{print $3,$4}' tmp.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
cut -d' ' -f3,4 tmp.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Trivial:

```
$ awk '{print $3,$4}' file
```

Did you do any research?

Answer (score 1):

`cut` and `awk` are your best bets. Here is how you'd do in `bash`:

```
while read -ra line; do echo "${line[2]} ${line[3]}"; done < tmp.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ echo x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7|sed -r 's/(\S+\s+){2}(\S+\s+\S+).*/\2/'
x3 x4
```

`\S+\s+` is approximately `$x` (awk).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'print "@F[2,3]"' your_file
```